# Array of ids sorted by another database field in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array of ids that is passed through javascript to a php file. In the php I receive an array with 5 elements like this example:

```
23
43
33
123
12
```

The database table is like this:

```
id
playerId
name
**position**
```

The array passed contains the playerIds (23,43,33,123,12) but I would like to sort that array by the database field **position** (not numerically).

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: Alright, I managed to solve the problem. I will leave the code in here in case it's helpful for anybody:

```
$v = $_GET['players'];
$sortedList = array();
$playerIdsStr = implode("," , $v);
$s = "select id from players where id in ($playerIdsStr) order by position";
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, $s);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{

    $sortedList[] = $r["id"];

}
```

$sortedList is the $v array but sorted by position. Just what I needed.

Comment: What is your server version?

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel, is this what you are asking for?? 

Versión PHP 5.6.30
Versión MySQL 10.1.37-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: Yes - That's what I mean. Too bad it's not MariaDB 1.3

Comment: why is that?????

Comment: MariaDB 10.3 supports VALUES table constructor: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f8ce96baf7b13c0701244f5632397545

Comment: Completely misunderstood your question :-)

Comment: Hahaha, no problem @PaulSpiegel. To be honest, I didn't really know how to explain what I was looking for. I know it in my head, but when it comes to a point where I have to explain it...Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
`select * from table_name where playerId in ('23','43','33','123','12') order by position`

Note: Please avoid `('23,43,33,123,12')` and use `('23','43','33','123','12')` OR `(23,43,33,123,12)`

Assume `$playerIds = [23,43,33,123,12];` then use:

```
$playerIdsStr = implode("," , $playerIds);
$sql = "select * from table_name where playerId in ($playerIdsStr) order by position"
```

This will work in case playerId field is a **integer** in the DB. For **string** use:

```
$playerIdsStr = implode("','" , $playerIds);
$sql = "select * from table_name where playerId in ('$playerIdsStr') order by position"
```

Comment: Hi Nikhill, thanks a lot for your quick answer. I receive the array as a variable, let's say $v, so I tried this: 

"select * from player where id in ('".$v."') order by position"

But, obviously, it doesn't work. 

Sorry for my low knowledge on this :( and thanks again!

Comment: converting array to string use `implode() ` function of php. suppose you have `array=[1,2,3,4]` by using `implode()` you will get `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Doing that I get a very long number without spaces nor commas. And, of course, when doing the query, it doesn't find any player. If I take that long number and I separate myself the different ids by commas, I only get the first player, but not the rest (I checked directly against the db in phpmyadmin).

Comment: If the SQL column is an integar type the quotes are not nessecary.

Comment: You have to write first parameter as comma like `implode(",",array)`.
`implode(separator,array)` check for more [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

Comment: @Martin right but if its character then don't forget to add individual quotes to each character

Comment: That worked!! Thanks a lot for your time and patience :). I edited the question to add the code I used to solve my problem, just in case it helps somebody else. Really appreciated your help @NikhilLende